# How to display result of an expression based on its data type in C

Tags: c, types

The following program displays a double expression result.

```
int main()
{
double a=5,b=10, sum; //I have to declare the types as double so I get the result in double, What I want is some way to get a floating sum when floats are added and int when ints are added (like expect 5+10 to be 15 not 15.00000)

sum = a+b;

printf("the sum is %lf \n", sum);

return 0; 
}
// the sum is 15.000000
```

How can I modify it to achieve something like below, without explicitly defining integer, float or double type?

Edit
Actually, I am saving the values of expression in a stack. So, currently I am using double type so the result of the expression is in double type, for example, 2+2 will be 4.0 but I want it to be as pure int 2, whereas if my expression result is a float then in this case I only want to see floating result like 4.2+1= 5.2

I am expecting some logic with unions and some typedef type where I can define int as 1 and float as 2 and then check if the expression result is floating at that time I set the result type as float on the other hand if the expression result is int I set the type as int

```
// 5+5 = 10
// 5.0+3.8 = 8.8
```

Here is my code where I am taking input from the user and checking if the character is number if yes then checking if its a float. Right now I am using double type for the number (yylval) to make my expression work with floating inputs from the user but what I want is to have some union or something that can check if the input expression has float numbers then answer should be float otherwise for integers only it should have integer result. I haven't added my expression evaluator code here.

Updated code syntax

```
while (ch==' '||ch=='\t'||ch=='\n') ch=getchar();

if (isdigit(ch)) {
    do {
        yytext[i]=ch;
        yylval=atoi(yytext);
        num = num * 10;
        num = num + yylval - '\0';

        ch=getchar();
    } while (isdigit(ch));
    yytext[i]=0;

if (ch == '.')
{
    ch=getchar();
    double weight;
    weight =1;
    while (isdigit(ch))
    {
        weight = weight / 10;
        double scaled;
        yytext[i]=ch;
        yylval=atoi(yytext);

        scaled = yylval  * weight;
        printf("scaled value in loop is %lf\n", scaled);
        num = num + scaled;
        ch=getchar();
    }
    yytext[i]=0;
}
yylval = num;

return(NUMBER); 
}
```

Comment: that's not how C works. The types of all expressions must be known at compile-time

Comment: `"%g"`? See [`printf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fprintf.html).

Comment: When you add `1.2 + 1.8` will you expect the sum to be `3` or `3.0`? I asked because your example has `5 + 10 = 15.000000`.

Comment: Your question is very unclear (and is understood differently in the two answers below). Please **[edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52577302/edit) your question** to improve it, check the wording in some dictionary (we both are obviously non-native English speakers), and add a few more paragraphs for motivation and context

Comment: @WeatherVane in this case i want 3.0. but if its 1+1 i want 2 not 2.0

Comment: Even if you save values on a stack, that does not tell much about what the *expressions* are

Comment: BTW, your question is probably some [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). You really should add motivation and context into it!

Comment: Even with the latest edit, your question is confusing. You speak of *expressions* that are *evaluated* at *runtime* and that could have different *types*. Please improve a lot your question (it needs several additional paragraphs). At least, provide several examples of input (and expected) output for your program, and if possible some [MCVE]

Comment: Still very confusing question, even with the latest edit. Do you want to *parse* expressions at runtime (it looks that yes)? Then give their *syntax* in your question. You look confused at several levels

Comment: Even the latest edit is still not an [MCVE], and I believe you need to learn about tagged unions. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25926895/841108) is a simple example mentioned in my answer

Comment: ok thanks ill look into them

Comment: You probably should upvote and perhaps accept my answer. However, next time please put a lot more efforts on asking a better question. Always add a few sentences on context and motivation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My own type that can evaluate the type of expression on runtime

If I guess what you mean, you want to have your own interpreter (for some domain specific language) in your C code (since you think of *expressions* that are *evaluated* at run time). For that, you should study basic compiler and interpreter concepts (so read the [Dragon Book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools) and Scott's [*Programming Language Pragmatics*](https://www.cs.rochester.edu/~scott/pragmatics/)), learn [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) techniques, and design your own scripting language and represent explicitly its [abstract syntax tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) in your program.

At the very least, I recommend specifying your input language (your "expression") in some kind of [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) notation. The wikipage on [recursive descent parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) contains a good example (and a C program).

But design and implementing your own interpreter takes a lot of time and efforts (however it is fun, IMHO). Did you consider instead *embedding* some *existing* interpreter, such as [Guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/) or [Lua](http://lua.org/), inside your own program?

Maybe you only want just simple arithmetic expressions (without variables). This is a classic parsing exercise, and even an [example](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Infix-Calc.html) in bison (a parser generator, improperly called compiler compiler).

---

> I am expecting some logic with unions and some typedef type

Maybe you want to represent your values (and perhaps even your expressions) as some variant type, i.e. some [tagged union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union) (or sum type; see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25926895/841108) example). Then [Glib's `GVariant`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-GVariant.html) could be useful or at least inspirational. Since Glib is [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) (and so are Lua or Guile), you could study its source code.

If you care about handling differently `1+2` and `3.5+2.5` you probably need some [type system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system). This is yet another reason to read more about interpreters, compilers, programming languages (and perhaps even Pierce's [*Types and programming languages*](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/tapl/))

If you need quickly something powerful (but well designed!), you should embed some *existing* interpreter in your program. In particular, you probably also want some variables and some functions in your "expressions" (then your thing is probably becoming [Turing-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness)).

Comment: Actually, I am saving the values of expression in a stack. So, currently I am using double type so everything is in a double type, for example, 2+2 will be 4.0 but i want it to be as pure int 2, whereas if my expression result is a float then in this case i only want to see floating result like 4.2+1= 5.2

Comment: Then your values have some tagged union type. But I still don't understand what your expressions are. Did you read my answer entirely? The first paragraph is as important as the others! And *please edit your question* to improve it

Comment: My expressions are simple like 10+5 (right now the answer is 15.00000, in this case i want 15), or the expression can be 10.3+5.2+5 (in this case the answer should be 20.5) P.S. in case of adding two simple integers the expression result should be pure int whereas in case of any floating point number in expression the result should be in float

Comment: Actually, I am expecting some logic with unions and some typedef type where I can define int as 1 and float as 2 and then check if the expression result is floating at that time i set the result type as float on the other hand if the expression result is int i set the type as int

Comment: That should go into your question. Please take time to read *carefully* my answer, follow the links there, etc...

Comment: The "logic with unions" is called a *tagged union* or sum type. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25926895/841108) example is mentioned in my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181022/discussion-between-ammar-ul-hassan-and-basile-starynkevitch).

Answer (score 2):

C has no run-time type introspection (except for very limited capabilities such as getting the size of a variable-length array). At compile time, you can select between types using `_Generic`:

```
#define Print(x)    \
    printf(_Generic((x),    \
            float        : "%g\n",  \
            double       : "%g\n",  \
            int          : "%d\n",  \
            unsigned int : "%u\n",  \
            long int     : "%ld\n"  \
        ), (x))


#include <stdio.h>


int main(void)
{
    Print(3u);
    Print(-4);
    Print(7.2f);
    Print(3 + 4.5);
}
```